# how do I restore a deleted organisation on github?

Tags: github, repository, github-organizations

I had an organization, then I deleted that. Now I've changed my mind, and I wanna work on that organization's repositories. Is there any way that I can undo that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm affraid not, found this on the official GitHub documentation:

[image]

https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/deleting-an-organization-account

Comment: What if I don't want to restore any content but just want to reclaim the organization name?

Comment: Turns out the organization name would be available to use again 90 days after removal.
[deleting-an-organization](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/deleting-an-organization-account)